# installing jdk1.7.0 on Ubuntu 11.04 machine

Tags: installation, java, ubuntu-11.04

I am facing a problem while trying to install Java 7 on Ubuntu.

The following are the steps that I performed for installing:

I installed the setup file from the link given below:

> wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u1-b08/jdk-7u1-linux-x64.tar.gz

1. I have a file: jdk-7u1-linux-x64.tar.gz
2. I Untared it:

   > tar -xvf jdk-7u1-linux-x64.tar.gz
3. `sudo mv ./jdk1.7.0_01 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_01`
4. `sudo update-alternatives –config java` 
   Here it gave me the following output:

   > There is only one alternative in link group java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java
   >   Nothing to configure.
5. `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_01/jre/bin/java 1`(I entered 1 here.)
6. `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
7. `java -version.`

It showed the following output

> java version "1.6.0_26"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)

I am not sure if jdk1.7.0 is installed as its showing the version as 1.6.0_26.

Comment: ideally the method described above should work like this: http://www.shinephp.com/install-jdk-7-on-ubuntu/ otherwise try this: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html

Comment: Try http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Answer (score 3):

this will install the new jvm into the java link group

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_01/bin/java 1
```

then, when you run this command again, you will see the list of JVMs that you are expecting.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```